# How build an application Alarm in Android

Tags: android, alarm

I have been searching the internet for an hour trying to find out how to create a reminder or an alarm in my android application. Does anybody know any tutorials for creating a reminder in your android app?

Its correct use notifications for sent all the alamrs?

affects battery consumption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to have an example app, you can get it [here](https://code.google.com/p/kraigsandroid/).

And [this](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html) is how you can download from github.